# Streamlining if-statement condition: 'result1' if a==b else 'result 2' or

Tags: python, if-statement

Any pointers to fix the complex arg below in "hours", i am getting

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

All I wanted is to reduce as much of the code as possible.
i want it at the end to give a value corresponding to value of i.

my code fails at

```
 (('($200 Hr) estimated at' if i ==1 )   or ('($130 Hr) estimated at' if i == 2 )   or ('($120 Hr) estimated at' if i == 3 )  or ('($125 Hr) estimated at' if i == 4)  or ('($90 Hr) estimated at'  if i == 5))
```

**Code:**

```
brs_items_list.append({                     
'desc' : kwargs["brs_d_{}".format(i)],
'hours' : kwargs["brs_hrs_{}".format(i)]+(' hour' if float(kwargs["brs_hrs_{}".format(i)])<2 else ' hours')+ (('($200 Hr) estimated at' if i ==1 )   or ('($130 Hr) estimated at' if i == 2 )   or ('($120 Hr) estimated at' if i == 3 )  or ('($125 Hr) estimated at' if i == 4)  or ('($90 Hr) estimated at'  if i == 5))   ,    
'cost' :  "${:,}".format(round(float(kwargs["brs_c_{}".format(i)]), 2))
})
```

Comment: `or ('($120 Hr) estimated at' if i == 3 )` what about else?, try `or ('($120 Hr) estimated at' if i == 3 else '')`

Comment: ... why don't you factor out that line into a function

Comment: i tried this already and does not spit anything

Comment: This is the way to go if you want to write unreadable code. Please refactor your function, it isn't even clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: If you want to reduce your code as much as possible, this is not the way to go about it. Look at your parens. The expression `('($200 Hr) estimated at' if i ==1 )` is trying to be evaluated by itself, which doesn't work without an `else` clause. Like `"foo" if True` is also a syntax error.... `"foo" if True else "Bar"` is valid.

Comment: my issue was int(i) i was using i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that I needed

```
brs_items_list.append({

'desc' : kwargs["brs_d_{}".format(i)],

'hours' : kwargs["brs_hrs_{}".format(i)]+(' hour' if float(kwargs["brs_hrs_{}".format(i)])<2 else ' hours')+ (('($200 Hr) estimated at' if int(i) ==1  else '')   or ('($130 Hr) estimated at' if int(i) == 2   else '')   or ('($120 Hr) estimated at' if int(i)== 3   else '' )  or ('($125 Hr) estimated at' if int(i) == 4  else '')  or ('($90 Hr) estimated at'  if int(i) == 5  else ''))   ,    

'cost' :  "${:,}".format(round(float(kwargs["brs_c_{}".format(i)]), 2))

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
{1:'($200 Hr) estimated at', 2:'($130 Hr) estimated at', 3:'($120 Hr) estimated at', 4:'($125 Hr) estimated at', 5:'($90 Hr) estimated at'}[i]
```

Even better, you have a lot of repeated text, so you can just do this:

```
'($%d Hr) estimated at' % {1:200, 2:130, 3:120, 4:125, 5:90}[i]
```

Comment: Amazing mate, I needed int(i)